# regex optional string in the middle followed by negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I have following entries of 3 allowed ip in a config file:
logging host 10.1.1.1
logging host ipv4 10.1.1.2
logging host 10.1.1.3

ipv4 is an optional string.I need to make sure that there are no entries with unallowed ip.For eg: if there is a line:
logging host 10.1.1.4
then the file is invalid because 10.1.1.4 is not one of the three allowed ip.I have come up with a Java regex to check for existense of any unallowed ip:

```
^logging host (ipv4\s)?(?!10.1.1.1|10.1.1.2|10.1.1.3)
```

It only works when the optional string ipv4 is not present and not when the optional string is present as in the case of second entry: "logging host ipv4 10.1.1.2".The regex engine in the first attempt greedily matches upto "logging host ipv4" and the remaining string 10.1.1.2 exists as one of the options in the negative lookahead condition.Then the regex engine makes a second attempt to non greedily match only upto "logging host" as ipv4 is optional and then remaining string becomes "ipv4 10.1.1.2" which does not exist in the negative lookahead condition and so returns this whole line as unallowed ip which is not true.
 What am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a partial match because you are not matching anything after the lookahead.

For example, in `logging host 10.1.1.1` the lookahead sees the value that is not allowed after matching `host` and there are no other options to explore so the match fails.

In `logging host ipv4 10.1.1.2` the ipv4 part will be matched. Then the lookahead will see the match that is not allowed. This time it can backtrack as the ipv4 part is optional. So it can get a match from the position before ipv4, and the match is `logging host`

---

You could shorten the pattern for the specific ip numbers to `10\.1\.1\.[123]`

For example

```
^logging host (ipv4\s)?(?!10\.1\.1\.[123])\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QOdofT/1)

Comment: @pradeepk6 The strings in the regex example start with logging host. Is that not your expected result? https://regex101.com/r/QOdofT/1

Comment: Thanks Bird.The 3 ip are only for demo purposes. The ip and number of entries can be anything.

Comment: @pradeepk6 Did it solve the problem / answer your question?

Comment: @pradeepk6 What happens is that you match this part `^logging host (ipv4\s)?` Now the position is after the space after host OR if ipv4 is present, the position is after the space for ipv4. Then the negative lookahead asserts (non consuming) that what is on the right is not one of the specified formats.

Comment: In the first case wihout ipv4 in the string, there is `10.1.1.1` to the right and it backtracks to see if there is an previous position to explore, but there is none so there is not match. In the case of `logging host ipv4 10.1.1.2`, the optional part will be matched, but then `10.1.1.2` is not ok. But as the ` ipv4` is optional, it can backtrack and from that position the lookahead is valid, so you get a partial match `logging host

Comment: @pradeepk6 You can extend the lookahead using the alternation `|` and in this case can also be written as `^logging host (ipv4\s)?(?!10\.1\.1\.[123]|ipv4)` See https://regex101.com/r/lV5BiI/1

Comment: Thanks Bird. I have bumped into something called Atomic Grouping:  
[regular-expressions.info/atomic.html]
How about this using Atomic Grouping instead of optional:
`^logging (?>host ipv6|host)? (?!10.1.1.1|10.1.1.2)`

Comment: Can you add some examples that you do and don't want to match which are not ip numbers? Using an atomic group prevents backtracking, in which context do you wich to use that?

Comment: Thanks bird. I resolved the negative condition. Cud you pls take a look at the postive condition of contais all and in a seperate line:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267115/regex-contain-all-and-only-each-in-a-seperate-line?noredirect=1#comment110124446_62267115

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to 'The fourth bird' for leading me to the answer with his important hints.
To summarize I need to ensure that the config file should not contain any unallowed logging host entries.The following are allowed host entries in the config file:

```
logging host 10.1.1.1
logging host 10.1.1.2
logging hsot ipv6 EFD7:DEA8:AEE4::11:3
```

**The tricky bit here is using an optional for ipv6 did not solve the problem due to backtracking at the optional**:

```
^logging host (ipv6\s)?(?!10.1.1.1|10.1.1.2|ipv6 EFD7:DEA8:AEE4::11:3)
```

The first solution uses Atomic Grouping to stop backtracking and the second solution is much simpler.

```
^logging (?>host ipv6|host)?\s(?!10.1.1.1|10.1.1.2|EFD7:DEA8:AEE4::11:3)  
^logging host\s(?!10.1.1.1|10.1.1.2|ipv6 EFD7:DEA8:AEE4::11:3)
```